# Kaniko reset build context in Gitlab pipeline

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci, kaniko

I detected following problem with Kaniko in GitLab CI:
Lets say I have this Dockerfile:

```bash
FROM nginx:latest
RUN mkdir test
```

Now I want to create two images from this Dockerfile. When building the second image it fails saying that the directory has been created already.

I think the reson of this has something to do with kanikos build context.

Do you have an idea how I can still build multiple images inside a single pipeline job using Kaniko?

Answer (score 1):

While it might be linked to the [Kaniko](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko) build context (since it does *not* depend on a Docker daemon and executes each command within a Dockerfile completely in userspace), a simple solution would be:

```
RUN mkdir -p test
```

That way, even if test already exist, it won't fail in error.

Comment: Its true, but it will fail at other commands such as `touch` and `git clone`

Comment: @Moritz That I didn't know: I tried to answer the original question.